# Send email programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I wrote a custom function called sendEmails in a script linked to a google spreadsheet. It works when I run the function through the script editor, however, it does not work when I run it through the spreadsheet.

My goal is to let the spreadsheet run without having a user and send an alert (in my case an email) automatically when a condition is met on the spreadsheet's cells.

This is the not working code:

```
=if(V3=X3,sendEmails(),"Waiting")
```

The alert can be anything that I can read using my phone or another computer.

Comment: You could consider using an onEdit trigger. (sorry, not sure why your code is not working)

Answer (score 2):

With custom functions you are limited by the kinds of services that you can use because custom functions never ask for authentication. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

You could add your function to the add-on toolbar or setup an installable trigger to run the `sendEmails()` function.

Here is some more documentation to help you out.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Without a look at the full list of code, it's difficult to say. Two possibilities based on your single line of code.

1) It's not enough to say `=if(V3==X3)` and assume that if they become equal, they will trigger. You must specify for the spreadsheet when it should check if these are equal (For example, on [spreadsheet edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit), or at a specified time interval).

2) In your if statement, you are specifying that V3 SHOULD equal X3, not checking if it is. `=if(V3==X3)` or `=if(V3===X3)` resolves this.